# PostgreSql using IN statemente with very slow performance

Tags: performance, postgresql

recently i've installed PostgreSQL 9.0 w/ Postgis on a windows7 machine. Then, i've loaded several tables into one schema.
Now, i want to do a very simple query and at this time, i can see that it takes more then 10minutes.
I've searched through alot of places, also in stackoverflow.com and until now i can understand what is my mistake.

**my problem:**

Tbl_Proprietarios - 230000 records

Tbl_Predio - 160000 records

```
SELECT id_predios 
FROM "Tbl_Predio"
where id_predios not in 
    (
    SELECT id_predios 
    FROM "Tbl_Proprietarios"
    )
;
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on `id_predios` column in both tables?

Comment: yes i have ( forgot to tell that )

Comment: Is id_predios's data type the same (presumably integer) in both tables ?

Answer (score 2):

Try a left outer join:

```
SELECT Tbl_Predio.id_predios
FROM Tbl_Predio
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tbl_Proprietarios ON Tbl_Predio.id_predios = Tbl_Proprietarios.id_predios
WHERE Tbl_Proprietarios.id_predios IS NULL;
```

Also, make sure that there is an index on `Tbl_Proprietarios.id_predios`.

Answer (score 0):

Should run in a few seconds on a decent machine.
Table definition ? Indexes ? query plan ? Configuration ? Memory?

```
SELECT id_predios 
FROM Tbl_Predio t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT *
  FROM Tbl_Proprietarios t2
  WHERE t2.id_predios = t1.id_predios
  )
;
```

EDIT:
Query plan with 2 * 999K records:

```
 Hash Anti Join  (cost=29813.47..61463.98 rows=79 width=4) (actual time=3470.658..7142.042 rows=1045 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (t1.id_predios = t2.id_predios)
   ->  Seq Scan on tbl_predio t1  (cost=0.00..13912.33 rows=999033 width=4) (actual time=0.038..1458.946 rows=999033 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=13911.54..13911.54 rows=998954 width=4) (actual time=3238.919..3238.919 rows=998954 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on tbl_proprietarios t2  (cost=0.00..13911.54 rows=998954 width=4) (actual time=0.057..1479.807 rows=998954 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 7143.919 ms
(6 rows)
```

EDIT2: 
the test script:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp;

DROP TABLE tmp.Tbl_Predio CASCADE;
DROP TABLE tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE tmp.Tbl_Predio ( id_predios INTEGER NOT NULL );
CREATE TABLE tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios ( id_predios INTEGER NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO tmp.Tbl_Predio ( id_predios) SELECT serie.val
    FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS serie(val)
    ;

INSERT INTO tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios ( id_predios) SELECT serie.val
    FROM generate_series(1,1000000) AS serie(val)
    ;

DELETE FROM tmp.Tbl_Predio WHERE random() <= 0.001 ;
DELETE FROM tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios WHERE random() <= 0.001 ;

ALTER TABLE tmp.Tbl_Predio ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_predios) ;
ALTER TABLE tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_predios) ;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT id_predios
FROM tmp.Tbl_Predio t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tmp.Tbl_Proprietarios t2
  WHERE t2.id_predios = t1.id_predios
  )
;
```

Comment: Your query suggestion is also slow :(

Comment: What flag of Configuration should i check ?

Comment: Your table definitions and query plan are also slow :-)

Comment: Memory (shared_buffers, effective_cache_size), file descriptors. Is your disk a real disk or a network thing?

Comment: shared_buffers = 32MB
effective_cache_size = 128MB
yes, its a real disk

Comment: Effective_cache_size is rather small (but: I don't know windows) Do you have sufficient statistics ? postgres-version ? SHOW US THE PLAN!!

Comment: shared_buffers = 32MB? That's just enough to start the database service... http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server and show us the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: On linux, I keep shared_buffers rather low, and trust on effective_cache_size ( := total_avalable - a few hundred MB for the processes to run). This relies heavily on the LRU disk-buffer management. Don't know about windows. BTW: normally all the query plans presented here should result in the same query plan.

Answer (score 0):

On my experience on SQL Server `in` operator usually is very slow.

Usually is better `exists`:

```
SELECT id_predios 
  FROM "Tbl_Predio"
 WHERE not exists (
           SELECT 1
             FROM "Tbl_Proprietarios"
            WHERE "Tbl_Proprietarios".id_predios = "Tbl_Predio".id_predios
       )
```

(Note in MySQL usually occurs the opposite, but logically depends the query you are running)

Or you can use a left join:

```
SELECT id_predios 
  FROM "Tbl_Predio"
  left join "Tbl_Proprietarios" on "Tbl_Proprietarios".id_predios = "Tbl_Predio".id_predios
 WHERE "Tbl_Proprietarios".id_predios is null
```

To know what is happening use [EXPLAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html).

Comment: i dont know how but both of your querys are fast and.... i've already tried to use Exists and LEFT JOIN's..... 

after 2 days on this... better to have a snack!

Thank you